# Android: multiple textviews in listview misprinting

Tags: android, listview, textview

My issue is as follow: Using this [example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-%E2%80%93-listview-%E2%80%93-2-custom-listview/), I tried creating a custom adapter for a listview that takes in 2 `ArrayLists` (names & numbers) from a database and outputs their data into the the textview in the list. The data gets shown in the list however they get shown individually, meaning that the name is shown the number and you can click on them separately rather than the two being together as one entry in the list. Attached is the necessary code.

My Adapter class:

```
public class ListViewCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  

    public Activity context;  
    public LayoutInflater inflater; 
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> nos = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context,ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<String> nos) {  
        super();  

        this.context = context;  
        this.names = names;
        this.nos=nos;

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
    }
    public int getCount() {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return names.size();  
    }  

    public Object getItem(int position) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return null;  
    }  

    public long getItemId(int position) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        return 0;  
    }  

    public static class ViewHolder  
    {  
        TextView txtViewName;  
        TextView txtViewNo;  
    }  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

        ViewHolder holder;  
        if(convertView==null)  
        {  
            holder = new ViewHolder();  
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editlist, null);  

           // holder.imgViewLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgViewLogo);  
            holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
            holder.txtViewNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);  

            convertView.setTag(holder);  
        }  
        else  
            holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();  

        //holder.imgViewLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);  
        holder.txtViewName.setText(names.get(position));  
        holder.txtViewNo.setText(nos.get(position));  

        return convertView;  
    }   


}
```

listview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:padding="5dip">  


    <TextView  
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="TextView"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/textView1"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">  
    </TextView>  

    <TextView  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:text="TextView"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/textView2"  
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"   
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip">  
    </TextView>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

the main activity the uses the adapter:

```
public class EditActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{
    Button b_add;
    ListView lv;
    SQLUtils sqlUtils = new SQLUtils(this);
     ListViewCustomAdapter adapter; 
     ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> nos = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.edit_layout);

         b_add = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b_add);
         b_add.setOnClickListener(this);
         lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         names=sqlUtils.getActions(1);
         nos=sqlUtils.getActions(2);

         //lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
         adapter = new ListViewCustomAdapter(this, names, nos);  
            lv.setAdapter(adapter); 
    }
[1]
```

Comment: Describe the problem. What do you mean they are misprinting? How is it misprinting? Does it only misprint when you scroll, or are the first few items misprinting too?

Comment: "you can click on them separately rather than the two being together as one entry in the list" Please post any click listeners you have implemented.

Comment: ok so you know how on an android phone you can go into your recently dialed tab and it shows you the name of the person and the number in one slot and when you click on it everything lights up. So thats what I am trying to do, but it ends happening is that the name gets outputted to one slot and the number to the other, and I am not sure why. I hope that made it clearer. Cheers

Comment: Ok, I sort of understand. Show us a screenshot so we can see what you see.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by your question, but looking at the tutorial and the difference in your code I will make a *blind* guess.

You extend a ListActivity not a regular Activity like the example, for a ListActivity you define an onListItemClick listener like this:

```
public void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
    String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2)).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Title => " + title + " => n Description " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry if the question was confusing I clarified it in the comments above

Answer (score 0):

If you want each item in the adapter to hold two TextViews, make your ViewHolder class extend LinearLayout and set it to vertical. Alternatively, you could use one TextView instead of your own class/linearlayout, and make it multiline and then set the text to name + "\n" + number